# Calendar MouseLeftButtonDown is fired after clicking outside of the component

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to raise event using MouseLeftButtonDown by clicking on a date in Calendar Control. But it is not raised until I click outside of this component.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<Controls:BasicCalendar Grid.Row="0"
                        x:Name="DemoCalendar" 
                        DisplayDate="{Binding Path=DisplayDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        HighlightedDateText="{Binding HighlightedDateText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        DateHighlightBrush="Gold">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
          <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="CalendarSelectDateEvent">
             <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=DemoCalendar, Path=SelectedDate}" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Controls:BasicCalendar>
```

Here is the event which I want to raise after clicking on some date in calendar:

```
public void CalendarSelectDateEvent(DateTime selectedDate)
{
  this.ActualCalendarEvents = this.CalendarEvents.Where(x => x.Date >= selectedDate).ToList();

  var a = this.ActualCalendarEvents;
  this.ActualCalendarEvents = null;
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ActualCalendarEvents);
  this.ActualCalendarEvents = a;
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ActualCalendarEvents);
}
```

When I tried to use Click event instead of MouseLeftButtonDown the Calendar Control was automatically handling it without firing CalendarSelectDateEvent. Is there a way to fire both events? (For Calendar Control selecting and highlighting the dat and for me CalendarSelectDateEvent)

Comment: Have you tryed with `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event?

Comment: Yes I did, but I need value from SelectedDate which does the Calendar Control explicitly. So when I use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown I dont have the right value in SelectedDate

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. It was really easy in the end. The Calendar Control has property SelectedDate. I just binded SelectedDate to my property SelectedDateChanged in code behind and when the SelectedDate changed I raise the event CalendarSelectDateEvent.

```
            <Controls:BasicCalendar Grid.Row="0"
                                    x:Name="DemoCalendar" 
                                    DisplayDate="{Binding Path=DisplayDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    HighlightedDateText="{Binding HighlightedDateText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDateChanged}"
                                    DateHighlightBrush="Gold">
            </Controls:BasicCalendar>
```

Like this:

```
public DateTime SelectedDateChanged
{
  get
  {
    return selectedDateChanged;
  }

  set
  {
    this.selectedDateChanged = value;
    this.CalendarSelectDateEvent(this.selectedDateChanged);
  }
}
```